# Dummy variables to index - inverse of dummyvar function?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of dummy variables, where each row is all 0 except for a single 1 indicating which class that sample is a member of.  For example `[1 0 0; 0 0 1]` indicates that the first sample is from class 1 and the second from class 3. I want a function that returns `[1; 3]`.

The function `dummyvar` is the inverse of what I want. Is there an elegant solution that doesn't require a for loop?

Comment: Can you just transpose the original matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `find` command.

```
dummy = [1 0 0; 0 0 1];
[idx,~] = find(dummy')
idx =
     1
     3
```

*EDIT*: In order to keep the proper order of more complex dummies, we have to get the row index of the transpose, instead of the more intuitive column index of the array. Thanks to @woodchips for spotting this!

Comment: This will fail, finding elements in the wrong order. Try it on the dummy variable array A = [1 0;0 1;1 0]; In that case, [~,idx]=find(A); will return [1 1 2], instead of [1 2 1].

Comment: Note that since it is the row order you wish to maintain, that [idx,~]=find(A'); WILL succeed, returning the vector idx=[1 2 1].